# How can I sort one column by ascending and another by descending in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Given the following page request let's say I wanted to Sort Descending by "created" but ascending by "name", how would I do that? the api doesn't seem to allow "direction" "field" pairs.

```
new PageRequest( 1, 15, Sort.Direction.DESC, "created", "name" )
```

using Spring Data JPA 1.6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
new PageRequest(1, 15, new Sort(
    new Order(Direction.DESC, "created"), 
    new Order(Direction.ASC, "name")
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new PageRequest(1, 15, Sort
         .by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created")
         .and(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name"))
```

Comment: Could you add what is this piece of code and how do you expect to help others?

Comment: @Anwarvic Its intended to answer the question. Using Spring Data Jpa (2.4.3) one really don't have to create instance of Sort or Order. in simple one line it can be read as: <br/>
**Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created").and(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name")**